# UILabel in Custom Cell doesn't wrap

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uilabel, word-wrap, custom-cell

I want to show a string with more words in a label.

Here is my code in the viewDidLoad:

```
startLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;  
startLabel.numberOfLines = 0;  
startLabel.text = string;
```

I also connected the label to the interface builder and synthesized it in my viewController.

But when the string is too long just the words who totally fit in the label get displayed and the rest gets cut off.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try add [startLabel sizeToFit]; on the bottom of that code.

Comment: sorry, doesn't work either.

Comment: have you implemented `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` ?

Comment: could you post an image of when it is working with few words and when its not working, with more words?

Comment: unfortunatelly my reputation is to low to post images.  But for example when the string is "Neufelden Busterminal" the "Busterminal" is to long to fit in the label so just "Neufelden" is shown.  Another example: string "Linz Hbf", everything is okay and the whole string is shown

Comment: @Simon it's a custom cell so I do not have any of the tableView code implemented